# Why is my text area disabled on Ipad?

Tags: html, css, ipad, blogs, textarea

I have a social network that allows people to ask questions and write blogs. For some reason on the ipad, you can write a title, and choose a category, but for some reason it will not let you write in the text area where one would compose their blog or ask their question. Is there some sort of special text area that ipad wants supplied?

Here is my simple text area code:

```
<textarea name="blogBody" cols="0" rows="0"><?php echo stripslashes($_POST['blogBody']); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: It could be to do with the `cols="0"` and `rows="0"`

Comment: What @chigley says. Also, is this within a form? Maybe it needs to be (although it should work on its own as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i gather setting the cols & rows to 0 disables it on ipad safari. you might want to set cols & rows first, then put the name attribute (and class and any other attributes that result in css being able to select it to style it) afterwards.

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="blogBody">...</textarea>
```

(edit - ninja'd!)

Comment: The order of attributes in an HTML tag shouldn't have any effect whatsoever (unless there's some dodgy browser quirks I'm unaware of!)

Comment: believe it or not, i actually came across a very similar issue, and it actually was fixed by putting class and/or id after rows & cols. if rows & cols are after class/id/style, they're liable to overwrite previous styling. this is my experience, anyways; i don't know for sure if it's (un)documented browser behavior or not. it also doesn't hurt to have your css selectors as specific as possible in cases like these.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem has been solved in the latest updates. To my surprise...